# sharepoint object model in webservice

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i am creating a webservice to provide one of the user poperty value to another application.
to do the same i am using sharepoint object model to connect to the mysite.

code : spsite site = new site(mysite url)

but i get the below error, kindly help.

error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at "mysite url" could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

Comment: Are you running this from the same server that SharePoint is installed?

Comment: yes i am running on the same server

Comment: I know the Sharepoint Documentation isn't great but I think you might be creating more work for yourself and adding complexity to your solution.
You really should not need to create new WebServices for Sharepoint, the standard exposed services will allow you to do 99% of the tasks you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things that might be the cause of your problem:

-If your SharePoint is 64 bits, your application has to be built in 64 bit. The same applies for x86.

-The Target Framework option in your application needs to be set to 3.5

EDIT: I found an article about it. Maybe you could benefit from it.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/09/19/common-issue-new-spsite-returns-quot-the-web-application-at-http-server-port-could-not-be-found-quot.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this is a WCF service then by default there is no httpcontext, ergo, no spcontext. The fix is to enable "asp.net compatibility mode" in web.config. This is done with the following directive:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: i do not find this directive on the webconfig,it is not a wcf